# SurfaceView thread - start / stop onDraw calls?

Tags: android

My surfaceView is running in a thread because at times it's animated , however
most the time it just needs to be re-drawn once and left in response to some user interaction , but because its running in the thread onDraw is continually being called... the constant re-draws are slowing it down and making my phone warm :)

I would like to use invalidate(Rect) but can't see how to do this when the thread is controlling onDraw ...

Everything constantly redrawing can't be the way i should go , any help will be greatly appriciated ...

Answer (score 0):

In your thread, you can call `wait()` after calling `onDraw()`. This will force the thread to sleep until prompted to continue working. Once the user has interacted and you want to resume animation, call `notify()` on the thread to wake it up and have it redraw.

If that doesn't exactly solve your problem, consider putting the `wait()` inside of an if statement so it will only happen after some condition is met.

Comment: thanks alot , ... ill have a look into that - it sounds perfect . Is the ability to specify a region to redraw just not possible when doing this? ... cheers

Comment: You could have a `setDirtyRect(Rect dirty)` method on your thread, and set a region before calling `notify()`. Just make sure to clean up by resetting/removing the dirty rect after using it.

Comment: i now have a method for synchronizing then Waiting or notifying the thread Object ... after a bit of work i've got it checking for no active pointers on pointer up then calling my wait() method unless animating... i still need to work on just updating the dirty region ... thanks for the advice